# Delaunay graph and hamiltonian paths

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry, hamiltonian-path

Does the Delaunay graph (dual of Voronoi) always contain a hamiltonian path (traceable)? I know the answer is negative for hamiltonian cycles since there are several examples such as the one gave by Dillencourt.

Reference:
Michael B. Dillencourtt. Toughness and Delaunay Triangulations. Discrete Comput Geom 5:575-601 (1990)

Comment: Good question.
But why don't you make a couple of references to the definition of the Delaunay graph and to the Voronoi diagram and the Dillencourt result. This would bring your question to the attention of a much wider circle of specialists.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this by now, but the answer is no. A counter-example exists with only 4 triangles. Consider an equilateral triangle split up into 4 smaller triangles of equal size (like the Legend of Zelda triforce). It's easy to see this is a valid Delaunay triangulation. The spanning tree has one triangle with a degree of 3 (the center vertex/triangle).